# \empheq piece-wise function with shadow box

Tags: box, empheq

I have written a piece-wise function using \empheq.

Is there a way to also write this function inside a shadow box with \empheq? I have done this for other equations but not for a piecewise function.

Code for piece-wise function:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{empheq}[left={f(x,y)=\empheqlbrace}]{alignat=2}
        & x^2 + (y-k)^2 = k^2 &&; 0 < x < p \tag {4.7} \label{eqn:4.7} \\
        & (b_2-q)(x-a_2) + (p-a_2)(y-b_2) = 0 && ;x \geqslant p \tag{4.8} \label{eqn:4.8}
    \end{empheq}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Piece-wise function]

Code for shadow box I have used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{empheq}[box=\shadowbox*]{equation*}
    x\,^{\prime}(x-a_o) + y\,^{\prime}(y-b_o) = 0  \tag{1.3} \label{eqn:1.3}
    \end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image: Equation with shadow box]

Please help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\begin{document}

    \begin{empheq}[left={f(x,y)=\empheqlbrace}, box=\shadowbox*]{alignat=2}
        & x^2 + (y-k)^2 = k^2 &&; 0 < x < p \tag {4.7} \label{eqn:4.7} \\
        & (b_2-q)(x-a_2) + (p-a_2)(y-b_2) = 0 && ;x \geqslant p \tag{4.8} \label{eqn:4.8}
    \end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]